# Is there software to send Internet connection from my laptop to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is there an iPhone app and software which let me send my 3G key Internet connection to my iPhone using Wi-Fi. It's kind of complex. Let me explain more.

1) I have an Intel Core 2 Duo laptop with Wi-Fi

2) I have a 3G key for Internet

3) I have an [iPhone 3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_3G)

I want to share my laptop connection with my iPhone using Wi-Fi or cable, so I work with 2 devices at the same time, is there a way?

I know there is a way to transfer Internet from iPhone to the laptop, but I want to do it from the laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Windows 7, then **[Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/)** may be for you:

> Turn your Windows 7 laptop into a WiFi
>   hotspot to share the Internet with
>   friends, co-workers, and mobile
>   devices.

Comment: Sounds interesting

Comment: Thanks Molly. I can't find any trace of a single user doing multiple down votes unless the anomaly scripts are getting to it before I do. However at this point there isn't any users with more then 5 down votes for you that raises suspicions.

Comment: Molly - you should mention that not all WiFi cards are supported by Connectify. My Intel Pro 3945 isn't :(

Oh wait, even if it was not supported, Connectify can create an ad-hoc network. My bad.

Comment: @ Diago: in this case the question and all answers were downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you using? If it's Windows XP or later, you can do this with the Internet Connection Sharing, and by creating an Ad-Hock wireless network.

Can't give you anything more specific unless you can tell us which OS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mac OS X, go to the Airport menu and select 'create network'.

Join the new network on your iPhone.

Details/screenshots here:
http://www.ehow.com/how_4504298_create-wireless-computer-computer-network.html

You will likely have to enable "Internet Sharing" under "Sharing" in system preferences and select your 3G key as the source.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable [ICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) on the 3G connection
2. Create an ad-hoc Wi-Fi network
3. Join your iPhone to the ad-hoc Wi-Fi network